# Best drawing material for creating an underdrawing on a primed and toned canvas

Tags: painting, oil-paint

I'm working on my first painting commission for a client and have finally reached the underpainting (underdrawing) stage — after months of composition drawings, photoshoots, etc., suffering innumerable stumbles and pitfalls.

I finally transferred the image to a primed and toned canvas using carbon paper and a large-format print of the reference photo.

Now I want to refine the drawing on the canvas.
It was suggested to me to use vine charcoal for this purpose — ostensibly when moving to the underpainting stage it is naturally wiped off, where graphite or other forms of charcoal would show through — but find that it doesn't adhere well at all to the primed, semi-smooth canvas.

Unfortunately, because of my NDA with the client, I can't show my work here, but could anyone who has ever encountered this suggest a better tool for creating the underdrawing?

Thanks for any insight!

Comment: Related: [What do I use to outline a sketch when I want to apply watercolour afterwards?](https://crafts.stackexchange.com/questions/8889/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few alternatives I can think of you can use to refine your underdrawing:

- Using a small brush you can paint the finer details, either with **acrylic** for quicker corrections, or already in **(diluted) oils**.
- Using a dip pen in combination with **acrylic inks** (I'm not sure how Indian inks will behave under oil paint in the long run).
- You can use **coloured pencils**, preferably choosing a colour that is only slightly darker or lighter than your imprimatura (just avoid graphite, as it will will really muddy up any lighter paint).
- If your imprimatura happens to be darker than white, another option is to use (a) **white chalk** (pencil), but this is not practical for detailed work.

As a footnote:

> "it is naturally wiped off"

This is not entirely true: while the application of the charcoal is usually so light that the mere proximity of a brush will sweep some of it away, it will likely at least partially mix with your paints.
This is obviously not necessarily a bad thing, especially in the underpainting stage, but just something to be aware of.

Comment: @pjldesign Please let me know what ultimately worked best for you, or anything you might want to add to this. Thanks in advance!